# load video to memory

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have 3-4 3 sec flv files and I need to play them multiple times.
I dont want to import the flv's and I cant load them dynamically everytime.
can I load them at the beginning of my swf ONCE and play it anytime I want ??
thanks

Comment: hope there is no other predefined way...

Answer (score 0):

The flash player will cache the FLV files once they are loaded, and if the URL for the media is the same as one previously loaded, will not attempt to download them again unless Flash players' cache is cleared.

Here's an example for preloading:

```
private var preloadQueue:Array = 
  ['http://path/to/firstmovie.flv',
   'http://path/to/secondmovie.flv'];

private function startPreload() {
   loadNextItem();
   function loadNextItem() {
     if (preloadQueue.length == 0) {
        preloadingFinished();
     }
     var movie:URLLoader = new URLLoader(new URLRequest(preloadQueue.pop()));
     cacher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, function (e:ProgressEvent) {
       //you can show the percentage of the current movie being loaded
     });
     //ideally you'd want to catch IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR as well for any 404's
     cacher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, function (e:Event) {
        loadNextItem();
     });
   }
}
startPreload();
function preloadingFinished() {
   MyFlvplayer.play('http://path/to/firstmovie.flv'); //movie will play instantly
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Video is loaded to memory.  Just as with any other item held in memory (such as an image, swf, object, array, etc...), if it no longer has a pointer to the data, the data is garbage collected.

In your case, if you've loaded a video once (be it dynamically or embedded at compile-time), that's all you need.  Just hide it until you need it again, and then reset it's playhead back to the beginning.

```
video.alpha = 1;
video.seek(0)
```